# R ggplot2 SVG poor image quality

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I'm creating a plot with ggplot2 in R. I'm using facet_wrap and the output contains around 50 panels.

Obviously, it's a lot of detail in a single image, so tickmark labels become unreadable in standard output. In my head, the way around that ought to be to export as SVG and figure out how to zoom in. However, the exported SVG file is huge and the quality of the displayed image is low making all details blurry.

If SVG is the way forward, how do I improve the image quality?

What should I be using instead of SVG to keep the file size small?

Thanks.

R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Chromium    43.0.2357.81 (Developer Build)
Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit))

As requested, some sample code

```
# Generate some data
id <- paste("Subject", rep(c(letters, LETTERS), each=7*8))
evt <- rep(paste("Event", 1:8), length.out=length(id))
days <- rep(rep(1:7, each=7), length.out=length(id))
value <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), size=length(id), replace=TRUE)
end <- sample(4:6, size=length(id), replace=TRUE)

d <- data.frame(id=id, evt=evt, days=days, value=value, end=end)
d$nevt <- as.numeric(d$evt)

# Do plot
ggplot(d, aes(days, nevt, colour=value)) + # call to geom_rect is lousy, I know
  geom_rect(data=d, aes(xmin=2, xmax=end, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
            alpha=.01, fill="goldenrod1", color=NA) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=15, alpha=.8) +
  facet_wrap(~id) +
  scale_y_continuous("", breaks=d$nevt, labels=d$evt) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

In case it's of interest, each subject is a patient in a clinical trial. They get treated from day 2 to 6 (the coloured background region), they have or do not have events 1 to 8 on each day, represented by the different coloured points.

Thanks, again.

Comment: If the SVG is blurry when displayed that is an issue with the software you use to display it and not with the SVG.

Comment: Give some sample code to generate a plot with 50 panels, the code t export it, and link to the SVG that you say looks blurry. Then we can compare...

Comment: I ran into that and found the svg files were not only very large, but did not look very good. I now render them into png at high resolution although I do have issues with the text size not scaling with the number of pixels. But it is very accurate and quite compact.

Comment: You could try saving as PDF and then convert this to SVG with other software.

Comment: I've given up. When exported as pdf, they render fine in most pdf viewers and the file size is ok. Not really a solution, tho

Comment: I gave up and used pdf. Not really a solution, though

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I dumped using svg(..., width=30, height=30) and then display it in a pannable, zoomable div: http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/

Zooming in with the browser (Chrome) causes it to rerender and display nicely. Zooming in with panzoom doesn't, whence the need to write a wide and big svg file.

Comment: `svgPanZoom` might be helpful for this situation https://github.com/timelyportfolio/svgPanZoom.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while trying to create heatmaps with a very large aspect ratio (height/width, *e.g.* 25in/3in). The text & lines were crisp but the tiles/colors were very blurry (in Inkscape and web browsers). My issue was the default dpi, which was too low (default: 300). 1200 dpi worked for everything I had. 600 might have worked as well but my file sizes were small so it didn't hurt. Since increasing dpi creates larger files this will only help with your image quality issue.